# Azure function ".NET 8.0 Isolated" isn t available in Visual Studio 2022 v17.9.3

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

After I have installed the latest .Net 8 version (currently v8.0.3) from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download and update Visual Studio to 17.9.3 (then restart), I cannot create a Azure function project with the .NET 8 because the entry is missing in the dropdown.

[image: Azure functions dropdown version]

I have updated Azure function core tools too (then restart Visual studio)
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools?tab=readme-ov-file#installing
but i cannot still view it ...

Answer (score 2):

After some google search, i have found the answer on a forum https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Net-8-is-missing-for-Azure-Function-proj/10520997

You can try the following steps to resolve this:

1. Navigate to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Azure Functions
2. Click on Check for Updates, then Download and install.

[image: Download and install template updates]

3. Restart Visual Studio

Et voilà ;)

[image: .NET 8.0 Isolated available]